# How to extract characters from a string based on the text surrounding them in R

Tags: r, string, character, extract

*Edited to highlight the language I'm using*  I'm using the R language and I have many large lists of character strings and they have a similar format.  I am interested in the characters directly in front of a series of characters that is consistently in the string, but not in a consistent place within the string.  For instance:

```
a  <- "aabbccddeeff"
b  <- "aabbddff"
c  <- "aabbffgghhii"
d  <- "bbffgghhii"
```

I am interested in extracting the two characters directly preceding the `"ff"` in each character string.  I can't find any reasonable solution apart from breaking each character string down using `grepl()` and then processing them each independently, which seems like an inefficient way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can match those two characters and capture them with sub and the right regular expression.

```
Strings = c("aabbccddeeff",
    "aabbddff",
    "aabbffgghhii",
    "bbffgghhii")
sub(".*(\\w\\w)ff.*", "\\1", Strings)
[1] "ee" "dd" "bb" "bb"
```

Explanation, This replaces the entire string with the two characters before the "ff".   If there are multiple "ff" in the string, this expression takes the two characters before the *last* "ff".

How this works: The three arguments to sub are:
   1. a pattern to search for
   2. What it will be replaced with
   3. The strings to apply it to.

Most of the work is in the pattern part - `.*(\\w\\w)ff.*`.   The ff part of the pattern must be obvious. We are targeting things near the specific string ff. What comes right before it is `(\\w\\w)`.  \w refers to a "word character". That means any letter a-z or A-Z,  any digit 0-9 or the one other character _. We want two characters so we have `\\w\\w`. By enclosing `\\w\\w` in parentheses, it turns this pattern of two characters into a "capture group",  a string that will be saved into a variable for later use. Since this is the first (and only) capture group in this expression, those two characters will be stored in a variable called \1. Now we want *only* those two characters so in order to blow away everything before and after we put `.*` at the front and back.  `.` matches any character and `*` means do this zero or more times,  so `.*` means zero or more copies of any character. Now we have broken the string into four parts:  "ff",  the two characters before "ff",  everything before that and everything after the ff. This covers the entire string. sub will _replace the part that was matched (everything) with whatever it says in the substitution pattern,  in this case "\1".  That is just how you write a string that evaluates to `\1`,  the name of the variable where we stored the two characters that we want.  We write it that way because backslash "escapes" whatever is after it.  We actually want the character \ so we write \ to indicate \  and \1 evaluates to \1. So everything in the string is replaced by the targeted two characters. We apply this to every string in the list of strings `Strings`.

Comment: Excellent.  That works great, thanks very much.  However, I'm having a hard time working out what is being controlled.  Can you walk me through the syntax within the `sub()` function?

Comment: Added to answer. Let me know if you need clarification.